# Pandas : If a column is having duplicates then copy values of corresponding column and copy it to new column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

If my dataframe is like this,

```
 X Y Z

 1 a

 1 b

 2 c
```

the output should be

```
X Y Z

1 a a,b

1 b a,b

2 c
```

Condition:

If a X has duplicates then it should all take the values of Y of that X duplicate and convert to csv values and paste in column Z

Comment: How is this a `jupyter` question?

Comment: working this on jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Z"] = df.X.map(df.groupby("X").agg(list).apply(lambda x: "" if len(x.Y) == 1 else ",".join(x.Y), axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `groupby.transform` and `mask`:

```
g = df.groupby('X')['Y']
df['Z'] = g.transform(','.join).mask(g.transform('size')==1, '')
```

output:

```
   X  Y    Z
0  1  a  a,b
1  1  b  a,b
2  2  c
```